# Problems while import/export of a .OBJ file

Tags: export, import, file-format

When we developed a basic model of the building and exported it to MAX in .OBJ format, the file forming new meshes connecting the original objects. When the mesh is deleted in MAX, the parts of the Objects are also deleted along with the mesh.

Comment: try importing back in blender to see where is the fault